# How to use static string as of private key to sign the message?

Tags: go, cryptography

I'm using `crypto` package to signing the data using below code. The DSA in the package is `ed25519` . In this code I want to using a static private key which is generated by other service(node js) into sign function which mention in the code.I have tried it but showing me the error

```
cannot convert "3ef8cc42c5c5ed0f7a11ef2045da509ed175074223c6ee1a6acc71c15b2a8a8a" (untyped string constant) to [64]byte
```

**CODE**

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    crypto "golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/sign"
)

func main() {

    signedData := crypto.Sign(nil, []byte("hello"), *[64]byte("3ef8cc42c5c5ed0f7a11ef2045da509ed175074223c6ee1a6acc71c15b2a8a8a"))
    log.Println(string(signedData))
    log.Println(signedData)

}
```

Can anyone help me in this? [library link](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20220829220503-c86fa9a7ed90/nacl/sign?utm_source=gopls)

Answer (score 2):

Your key is (hex decoded) only 32 bytes and is only the seed, you have to append the 32 bytes public key, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54367):

```
3ef8cc42c5c5ed0f7a11ef2045da509ed175074223c6ee1a6acc71c15b2a8a8ae2f5b5f7c272360a8292b796c1dc28e8b15f415c9c3680bcae927dda3458261b
```

and hex decode the full key. Overall:

```golang
import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"
    crypto "golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/sign"
)

func main() {

    decoded, _ := hex.DecodeString("3ef8cc42c5c5ed0f7a11ef2045da509ed175074223c6ee1a6acc71c15b2a8a8ae2f5b5f7c272360a8292b796c1dc28e8b15f415c9c3680bcae927dda3458261b")
    var key [64]byte
    copy(key[:], decoded)
    signedData := crypto.Sign(nil, []byte("hello"), &key)
    log.Println(string(signedData))
    log.Println(hex.EncodeToString(signedData))
}
```

The code gives for the hex encoded signature:

```
560f119fd68a647eb9ff10fa83fff71713e377d041c7b076873bed767ed15bae74ff7822764636bfadc2afc4f430e93f32df6c7ba8b904f6055fc9b32fe85f0268656c6c6f
```

where the message `68656c6c6f` is attached.

---

You can e.g. use [this online tool](https://ed25519.herokuapp.com/) and generate a signature for the same key and the same message. Since Ed25519 is deterministic, the same signature is always generated for the same input data. The test shows that both signatures match, so the above code is successfully tested.
Note that the tool does not append the message and that it uses Base64 encoded data for key and signature.